# How to Sample From Unit Simplex According to Multi-Modal Distribution

Tags: sampling, multimodality

I need to sample $n$ points from a multi-modal distribution with the condition that the sum of the points equal 1, i.e., the points are the unit simplex. The possible distributions may have varying numbers of modes. How would I do this?

I have found [research](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Enasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf) on how to do this if the distribution is the uniform random distribution but I can not find anything on how to do this for a multi-modal distribution or an arbitrary distribution.

In practice what I want to do is as follows: 
I have a a multi-modal distribution of points that sum up to 1 according to real world data, and I want to generate synthetic data according to that distribution while preserving the condition that the points sum up to 1.

Below is a few examples of distributions with varying numbers of modes plotted as KDE plots. Note that the distributions are bounded by [0, 1] which is not reflected by the KDE plots.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us its form?

Comment: @utobi I have edited the post to include a graph doing so.

Comment: The question does not permit a specific answer because you don't explain anything about the phenomenon you are modeling apart from the need for multimodality.  It is likely a mixture of Dirichlet distributions would work but it's impossible to tell for sure from this limited information.